# Azure Automation - Login with AD User throws error

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-authentication

I am trying to login to Azure from Azure Automation using my AD credential. However seems like I am doing something wrong and it's throwing error while testing.

```
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'DefaultAzureCredential'

$null = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable err
if($err) {
    throw $err
}

Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "my-resource-group"
```

**Error:**

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup : No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are 
authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Login-AzureRMAccount to login.
At line:8 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "my-resource-group"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmResourceGroup], ApplicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.GetAzureResourceGroupCommand
```

**Update:**

When I run `Get-AzureRm-Context` from Azure Automation script it shows me following which is completely different than when I run the same command from `Azure Cloud Shell`. Should I do things differently ?

```
Account Environment Subscription Tenant
------- ----------- ------------ ------
        AzureCloud
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error, i do not see an issue with Login or credential.  The error is in the `get-AzureRmResourceGroup` **No subscription found in the context**.

This happens when credential provided does not have a subscription.  If you are sure account has subscription, then the issue might be with the module loaded in Azure Automation.

Comment: you are correct !!.  I have access to subscription. If I run the same command from `Azure Cloud Shell` I get information I want.

Comment: If you have a subscription it looks like you have limited access to it.  When you do `Get-AzureRmContext` it should show you Subscription and tenant information, like https://i.imgur.com/WbhilFy.png

Comment: I have already mentioned what I see, when I run `Get-AzureRmContext` from my Azure Automation script. Which is totally different than what I am getting  when I same command from Azure Cloud Shell. And that's the whole point.  Do I have to do thing differently ?